# Upgraded to the latest EF (4.1) from CTP - how do we override underscores generated in foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

We recently upgraded our EF implementation from the CTP to the latest release of EF (4.1).  We are now seeing an issue in that the foreign keys that are generated are now generated with an _ where previously there was none.  As we have a couple of references to the previously generated names we find that our code is choking on the new format.  Is there a way to override this behavior and generate foreign keys without the _?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override the behavior globally but you can override it for each generated foreign key.

Suppose that you have entity A with FK to B. You can use this fluent mapping to control naming of FK in the database:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.B)
            .WithMany(b => b.As)
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("YourKeyName"));
```

This example expects A with required navigation property to B (FK is not nullable) and B with collection navigation property As containing all related A instances.